# Animating div to move between container divs in React - react-pose?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, animation

https://codesandbox.io/s/jvq5yk1n29

This little sandbox moves a dot back and forth between five `material-ui` `Paper` boxes when arrow keys are pressed. How would I create a smooth animation as it moves from box to box? I came up with a very convoluted `react-pose` solution that constantly polls the `getClientBoundingRect()` on the container DOM elements in order to move the dot with absolute coordinates. But that's just a pain. There must be something more elegant? I can't use CSS (?) since the div is constantly being remounted, leaving nothing for an animation to hook onto. What gives?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that with a combination of `JS` and `CSS`.

Here're the steps:

1. Make the `dot` element ready to move right or left(in CSS).
2. Create a state variable that keeps a track from which side (e.g. `left` or `right`) the dot comes in.
3. Pass the state variable to your `Dot` component and change the style accordingly.

> [image: Edit Dot on the move]

This technic gives you really the flexibility on how you want to animate your element in `React` using the `state`.

> Bonus: after I read your code, I'd like to recommend you the following:

- Try always to use `===` with your comparisons.
- Any element that's absolutely positioned, its parent should have relatively positioned (i.e. `position: relative`)
- Try not to duplicate your CSS rules.

Hope that helped! Let me know if it isn't clear!

Comment: Thank you! That works great for when the boxes are fixed. But doesn't this method break down once you introduce `Grid` breakpoints, rows, window resizing etc?

Comment: Had a closer look at your example on the desktop rather than my phone. It'll obviously work under any circumstances, but I've been trying to get the div to fly over the boxes, rather than inside them. That's another kettle of fish.

Comment: Of course you'd have to make it responsive and look nice on every platform you could think of; which is a matter of changing the `CSS` logic. The purpose of my example is to explain how it could be managed in `React`.

Comment: Absolutely. Thanks! Do you have any suggestions as to how to fix the dot disappearing (due to it being remounted and re-rendered) before rolling into the next box?

Comment: For that you can remove the `overflow` property on the `container` element :)